# Passing additional information to View

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to handle Django form in a more gentle way and actually, I have no idea how to push further this topic. I have a View which is responsible for displaying a Form, in If form.is_valid() condition I am looking for free parking spots, if I found nothing then I would like to show an Error to the user or pass to context additional data. Fist part I've covered easily but I have no idea how to show an error or something similar.

```
class BookParkingSpot(FormMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'parking/book_spot.html'
    form_class = BookParkingSpotForm
    model = ParkingBooking


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = BookParkingSpotForm(self.request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            parking_spot_list = ParkingSpot.objects.all().exclude(
                parkingbooking__booking_time_start__lte=form.instance.booking_time_end,
                parkingbooking__booking_time_end__gte=form.instance.booking_time_start
            )

            if parking_spot_list.exists():
                random_spot = random.choice(parking_spot_list)
                reservation = ParkingBooking.objects.create(
                    car=form.instance.car,
                    booking_owner=self.request.user,
                    spot=random_spot,
                    booking_time_end=form.instance.booking_time_start,
                    booking_time_start=form.instance.booking_time_end,
                )
                return redirect(reservation.get_absolute_url())
            else: # this part doesn't work
                context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
                return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
```

Any idea how to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best write your validations in the form methods. Read about in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class BookParkingSpotForm(forms.Form):
    # ...

    def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super().clean()

       p_list = ParkingSpot.objects.all().exclude(
           parkingbooking__booking_time_start__lte=cleaned_data.booking_time_end,
           parkingbooking__booking_time_end__gte=cleaned_data.booking_time_start
        )
        if p_list.count() == 0:
            raise ValidationError('Your error message')
```

And to access to the form data use `form.cleaned_data['field_name']` and not `form.instance.field_name`.

Comment: Definitely looks better but why don't use a "rise" before ValidationError?

What is a difference or impact between those two access methods?

Comment: Yes, @SerSergious, I forgot the "rise".

Comment: First for all sorry for typo, it should be "raise". Nevertheless, I've added a raise keyword before ValidationError and now I am getting this error if form validation hitting this condition:

"The view parking.views.view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Comment: I have always used the `cleaned_data` attribute, because it is common in normal forms and model forms, and according to the docs:  "Failed validation may leave the underlying model instance in an inconsistent state and therefore it’s not recommended to reuse it". About the error in the view, you aren't return anything when the form is not valid. You may need move left the last "else".

Comment: Again exactly in point!  But on other hand, is there any way to pass objects between Form validation and View? Or do I have to make an additional query for that?

Comment: You can "cache" it in a form property, using `self.p_list` instead `p_list` and access in the view with `form.p_list` after validate the form.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone for the inconvenient but again after posting on StackOverflow I figured out how to resolve this issue and it was very simple, I am still learning Django ;)

So the answer to my question lies in the last part of my code, if I didn't find any free parking spots then I can render the same page with additional data like on below example and pass form object to context:

```
return render(self.request, 'parking/book_spot.html',
                          {'errors': "There are no free parking spots in selected time",
                           'form': form})
```